# Jquery, return id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple button elements with the following id assigned = 'saveXX' and corresponding paragraph elements with an id assigned = 'contentXX', the contentEditable attribute for the paragraph elements is set to true.

The following works and updates the database:

```
$(document).ready(function(argument) {
    $('#save81').click(function(){
        $edit = $('#content81').html();
        $cid = '81';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/editupdate.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {data: $edit,cid: $cid},
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function(rsp){
                alert(rsp);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My question which I can't crack - how do I run the above code for any id='saveXX' button and corresponding id='contentXX' paragraph element? The XX relates to the database record.

Much appreciated, Stew

Comment: I think you can replace `function(argument)` by `function()`. According the documention of Jquery the definition `$cid =` is wrong. You have to just use `cid =`.

Comment: Without seeing what your HTML looks like, it's hard to give suggestions, but assuming every `#saveXX` has a common class, you can get the `id` through use of `$('classname').attr('id')` and then look for the element with the appropriate `#contentXX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a common class across all buttons, and extract the number id from the element:

HTML:

```
<button id="save81" class="save">Save 81</button>
<button id="save82" class="save">Save 82</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (argument) {
    $('.save').click(function () {

        id = $(this).attr('id').replace('save','');

        $edit = $('#content' + id).html();
        $cid = id;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/editupdate.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                data: $edit,
                cid: $cid
            },
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function (rsp) {
                alert(rsp);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am using bootstrap, will the above still work ok i.e: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="save81">

Comment: @Stew You should be able to select on the `btn` or `btn-default` or `btn-sm` (or any combination thereof).

Comment: Thats great - many thanks for the quick response, I used your code and replaced the .save with .btn.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather store the number part in data attribute:

`<input type="button" data-function="update" data-id="81" />`

And modify the script to work with it:

```
$(input[data-function='update']).click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use joker on selector like that :

```
$('input[id^=save]').click(function(){
```

More details here : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Then you can get the number like that :

```
var contentID = $(this).attr('id').replace('save', 'content');    
$edit = $('#'+contentID).html();
$cid = $(this).attr('id').replace('save', '');
```

or with a regex to get lasts digits.